# ToolbarItem in ToolbarItems for iOS not in the right place

Tags: maui

In my `ContentView`, I like to display an icon on the toolbar to add a new *book* (this is my class). The `ToolbatItem` has an icon from *bookadd.svg* and a text. The render is in the following screenshot.

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Add" IconImageSource="bookadd.png" 
                 Priority="1" Order="Primary" 
                 Clicked="OnAddNewItem" />
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

[image]

How you can see, the render in Android is what I expect but in iOS the icon has a space on the right. How can I fix it?

Comment: The issue is that ToolbarItems with Icons won't align properly on iOS and it is an unresolved issue on Xamarin, see https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/3513.As an alternative solution, you can try to use custom handler to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm just starting with MAUI. I don't know how to create and use a custom handler. I tried the code in the GitHub link but it is obsolete. Do you have any other links? Thank you in advance.

Comment: No worries, I've updated an answer. You can refer to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the capability of `FontImageSource`, the added icon on the toolbar can align properly on iOS as render on Android.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Clicked="OnAddNewItem">
      <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource
          FontFamily="yourfontfamilyname"
          Glyph="&#xe518;"
          Color="White"
          Size="35" />
      </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

For more details, you can refer to [Display font icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts#display-font-icons) and [Custom Fonts & Material Design Icons in .NET MAUI](https://cedricgabrang.medium.com/custom-fonts-material-design-icons-in-net-maui-acf59c9f98fe).