# ToolbarItem differences between Android and iOS - Title missing in iOS

Tags: maui

In my .NET MAUI App, I use different Views which are dynamically displayed. Based on the View also other UI elements will be visible.

The title of the Page that is currently displayed should also change dynamically based on the View.

For one of my Views, I want to show a "+" (actually an IconImage) ToolbarItem on the right upper corner.

Therefore, I dynamically create the ToolbarItem like this:

```
private void CreateAddNewToolbarItem()
{
    var addNewToolbarItem = new ToolbarItem();

    addNewToolbarItem.IconImageSource = "plus.png";
    addNewToolbarItem.SetBinding(ToolbarItem.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(MainPageViewModel.MainPageTitle)));
    addNewToolbarItem.Text = mainPageViewModel.MainPageTitle;

    ToolbarItems.Clear();
    ToolbarItems.Add(addNewToolbarItem);

    NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, CreateTitleView());
}

private View CreateTitleView()
{
    var titleView = new Label
    {
        Text = mainPageViewModel.MainPageTitle,
        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand
    };

    return titleView;
}
```

The **CreateTitleView** was only introduced as it does not work with the `addNewToolbarItem.Text = ...`.

On **Android** it looks like it should:

[image]

whereas on **iOS** the **Title is missing** and also the "+"-Icon is not in the upper right corner:

[image]

How can I display the Icon in the right upper corner and display the Title correctly on **iOS**?

==== Setting a FontImageSource in Code-Behind as recommended in Comment ====

```
private void CreateAddNewItemToolbarItem()
{
    var addNewToolbarItem = new ToolbarItem();

    var fontImageSource = new FontImageSource(); //new FontImageSource("plus.png", ;
    fontImageSource.FontFamily = "yourfontfamilyname";
    fontImageSource.Glyph = "&#xe518;";
    fontImageSource.Color = Colors.White;
    fontImageSource.Size = 35;

    addNewToolbarItem.IconImageSource = fontImageSource;
    addNewToolbarItem.SetBinding(ToolbarItem.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(MainPageViewModel.MainPageTitle)));

    ToolbarItems.Clear();
    ToolbarItems.Add(addNewToolbarItem);

    NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, CreateTitleView());
}
```

[image]

==== Additional change: ====

```
private void CreateAddNewItemToolbarItem()
{
    var addNewToolbarItem = new ToolbarItem();

    var fontImageSource = new FontImageSource();
    fontImageSource.Glyph = "+";
    fontImageSource.Color = Colors.White;
    fontImageSource.Size = 30;

    addNewToolbarItem.IconImageSource = fontImageSource;
    addNewToolbarItem.SetBinding(ToolbarItem.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(MainPageViewModel.MainPageTitle)));

    ToolbarItems.Clear();
    ToolbarItems.Add(addNewToolbarItem);

    NavigationPage.SetTitleView(this, CreateTitleView());
}

private View CreateTitleView()
{
    var titleViewLabel = new Label
    {
        Text = mainPageViewModel.MainPageTitle
    };

    var horizontalStackLayout = new HorizontalStackLayout();
    horizontalStackLayout.Children.Add(titleViewLabel);

    return horizontalStackLayout;
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is currently is a problem with the TitleView on iOS, but Shane from the MAUI team has provided a workaround here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PureWeen.Maui.FixesAndWorkarounds. Note that you should wrap your `titleView` inside of a Layout, e.g. a Grid or HorizontalStackLayout. **Note:** The `CenterAndExpand` and other `*AndExpand` options are deprecated in MAUI.

Comment: Thanks, I deleted it and left the Code as in the second additional comment above. Like that it seems to look fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `ToolbarItems` with `IconImage` won't align properly(to the right side) on iOS as render on Android.

However, you can try to use `FontImageSource` as this displays the Icon in the right upper corner on iOS as on Android.

You can refer to the sample code below:

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Clicked="OnAddNewItem">
      <ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
        <FontImageSource
          FontFamily="yourcustomfont"
          Glyph="&#xe518;"
          Color="White"
          Size="35" />
      </ToolbarItem.IconImageSource>
    </ToolbarItem>
</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

For more details, you can refer to [ToolbarItem in ToolbarItems for iOS not in the right place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76731419/toolbaritem-in-toolbaritems-for-ios-not-in-the-right-place/76736477#76736477) and [Fonts in .NET MAUI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/fonts?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-50033).

Comment: This could work in general, but my problem is, this "+"-Icon should only be available when a certain View was loaded and otherwise it should not be visible. That was the reason I was creating the ToolbarItem in the Code-Behind.
Do you know, how I could do about the same as above in Code-Behind and also use my own IconImage so that it renders correctly in the upper right corner?

Comment: For now, can you dynamically add the `+` in code-behind after the certain view was loaded?

Comment: I tried it in Code-Behind with an FontImageSource, but the Glyph does not evaluate to a "+" (see additional comment in original question). My loaded fonts from MauiProgram.cs are ```.ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
   {
    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
   });```

Comment: @OXO that's an example on how to use it. You can't simply copy it to your project. You should configure your [own font](https://askxammy.com/adding-fonts-in-net-maui/) in MauiProgram.cs and then use it. Consider using [fontawesome](https://fontawesome.com/icons/plus?f=classic&s=solid), see [FontAwesome](https://medium.com/xamarinlife/fontawesome-in-xamarin-forms-everything-you-need-to-know-b187af338e30) and [Use FontAwesome](https://medium.com/@tsjdevapps/use-fontawesome-in-a-xamarin-forms-app-2edf25311db4).

Comment: Have some difficulties to create my own TTF with an image inside. On FontAwesome I can just see free SVGs, but no TTF. I just stayed with the configures fonts and used a simple "+" in my glyphs which seemed to provide the right effect. Also the Title is now dependent on the loaded View. Couldn't set a Margin for the FontImageSource, but maybe its already good enough. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, there's no Margin property for the FontImageSource, however, at least, you are in the right direction.